# Чтение звука и транслирование его на устройство (в Windows)

Tags: windows

Требуется воспроизводить аудио файл в микрофон(ПРОГРАММНО!), например.
Какие для этого есть средства в винде?

Comment: воспроизводить в микрофон? наверно, можно воспользоваться паяльником.

Comment: @alexander-barakin, попробуй воткнуть наушники в микрофонное гнездо, включить программу записи звука и наговорить что-нибудь. Уверен, будешь удивлён.

Comment: @donRumata всякий, хоть немного помнящий школьную физику, удивлен не будет. А вот сделать вход выходом, если такая возможность в кристалле не заложена, нельзя. Нельзя сделать из АЦП-входа ЦАП-выход, если такая возможность в кристалл не заложена.

Comment: @Владимир-Мартьянов, ну я так понимаю, что речь идёт про абстрактную звуковуху, у которой эта возможность есть. Потому и написано, что выводить нужно програмно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В винде есть такое записывающее устройство - Stereo Mix. Как раз позволяет воспроизводить звуки в микрофон (виртуальный).  Проблема в том, что Stereo Mix передает все звуки, воспроизводимые на компьютере, а не только звуки вашего приложения.

Не думаю, что можно воспроизводить звуки, как будто они идут из реального микрофона.
Программы вроде "Skype Voice Changer" создают виртуальное аудиоустройство и транслируют звуки с реального микрофона на виртуальный.

Чтобы создать "виртуальный микрофон", наверно, нужно писать собственный аудиодрайвер.

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно!